# Can $(A^T B^{-1} A)^{-1}$ be simplified if A is non-square?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can $(A^T B^{-1} A)^{-1}$ be simplified if $A$ is non-square, and $B$ is SPD?

The two inverses are begging to be cancelled out, but $A$ being non-square makes that not possible, as far as I can tell.
In my particular case, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{4\times2}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{4\times4}$. So the result of this expression is in $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$.

Rewriting $B=LL^T$ with $L$ its Cholesky decomposition doesn't reallly help:

$$(A^T B^{-1} A)^{-1} = (A^T (LL^T)^{-1} A)^{-1} = (A^T (L^{-1})^T L^{-1} A)^{-1} = ((L^{-1} A)^T (L^{-1} A))^{-1}$$

While it looks pretty, and is probably numerically more stable, I wouldn't say it's simplified. Clearly, $A$ keeps being in the way, and we are still left with the two matrix inversions.